# Get indexes that list items start to change

Tags: python, list

I have a list that contains number of strings that change after several consecutive repetitions of a string. Let me explain with an example: If I have this string

```
lst = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'D', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'W']
```

I want to get a list of items where the elements in that index have started to change (including the first item list), so the output should be like this:

```
out = [0, 4, 8, 9, 10]
```

How can I do this in the best possible way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
[i for i, z in enumerate(lst) if z != lst[i - 1] or i == 0]
```

haven't tested this, but it should work I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `for` loop that can get the job done for you. It iterates through the list and checks to see if each value it contains is different from the previous one it identified. If so, it adds the index to a list and updates its `curr_val`.

```py
lst = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'D', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'W']

def find_change(lst):
    curr_val = ''
    indices = []
    for i,v in enumerate(lst):
        if curr_val != v:
            indices.append(i)
            curr_val = v
    return indices

i = find_change(lst)
print(i)
```